# Using Script Engine Manager in Android to evaluate infix expressions

Tags: java, javascript, android, infix-notation

I want to implement the following code in Android. How do I do that?

```
System.out.println("Enter a String");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = sc.next();

System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(string));//this is solving infix expression using javascript
```

Comment: The Android API, doesn't provide such a class. However, you could simply implement your own stack to evaluated an expression. See the second answer of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185589/how-to-calculate-expression-in-java

Comment: I have added jav8-jsr223-win-amd64-0.6.jar in lib and i am able to use these statements in my app but the app crashes when i execute.eval().. is there any solution to it?

Comment: Well I have no experience with this library, but posting the relevant android code and the stacktrace would be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
     final ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("Jav8");   String text2=filter(userInputText.getText().toString()); try {
        userInputText.setText((engine.eval(text2)).toString());
       } catch (ScriptException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

Comment: Post it in the question by editing it, and please use a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast it? like this,

```
double a = (double) engine.eval("25+36");
```

or this (toString());

```
System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(string).toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I wrote a custom parser.

Comment: I ever tried it. It worked. Hope you found the best one. Regards.

Comment: It works in java when you are printing to console but in android it does not work because you are displaying the result in a text view or something else but not the console.